# How to use images in SWT Text field?

Tags: java, textbox, swt, emoticons, styledtext

I'm creating a chat like application with SWT. My application uses `StyledText` and `Text` for taking input and displaying it to user. Is there a way I can insert emoticons (images) into the text field?

Comment: I would suggest posting this question over on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  also padding out your requirements a little.

Comment: You can look at [this snippet](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet212.java) for an example of how to add actual images to StyledText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Unicode characters for Emoticons (starting with Unicode 6.0) so you don't need to use images for this provided you have a font which supports them

The Unicode characters are in the range U+1F600..U+1F64F, more information on the characters see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_%28Unicode_block%29)

Comment: But is there a way to add images or icons in case of custom emoticons?

Comment: See the comment I just added. This can be done for StyledText but not for Text